# Get text between brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string : `Charles de Gaulle, (Paris) [CDG]`

I would like in JavaScript/jQuery get just `Paris`. The initial string can have variable length.

I have tried this:

```
var tab = "Charles de Gaulle, (Paris) [CDG]";
var tab2 = tab.split(','); 
var tab3 = tab2.split('[')
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: 1/ var tab = "Charles de Gaulle, (Paris) [CDG]"; 2/ var tab2 = tab.split(','); var tab3 = tab2.split('[')

Comment: Best way is to first give it your own thinking and then ask others.

Comment: 1/ var tab = "Charles de Gaulle, (Paris) [CDG]"; 2/ var tab2 = tab.split(','); var tab3 = tab2.split('[') –

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
var myString= "Charles de Gaulle, (Paris) [CDG]";
var result = myString.match(/\((.*)\)/);
alert(result[1]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1500/)

Comment: If the text includes multiple parenthesis, how could you get these values? Eg: `var myString= "(Charles) de (Gaulle), (Paris) [CDG]"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.slice(begin,end)` instead of `.substring()`.

For example click on the link to view your result: http://jsfiddle.net/qhZq5/

Comment: This is the best answer to this I have found so far, but how could you make this work if there are multiple instances of words inside '()'? Right now this only works with the first word inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

here is my code

```
"This is (my) text".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]
```

The match() returns an array ["(my)","my"] from which the second element is extracted.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str = "Charles de Gaulle, (Paris) [CDG]",
pos = str.indexOf("(") + 1;
str = str.slice(pos, str.lastIndexOf(")"));
```