# GET item from brackets in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help. Here I have a string.

```
n[0] = '3(10)';
```

The task is to get only 10 from brackets. How to do it in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show some attempt of your own. What format is the string in? Is it always `[digit]([two digits])` or can it be different? This is a good task for [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Review the list of string operations in JavaScript and combine few methods to get desired output http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: here is types of question and answer already available
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377113/get-text-between-brackets

Comment: thanks guys. I have the last one question I have 

    a[0] = '3(10,5) 7(9,4)';
10 and 9 are chances
the task is to get the number (3  or 7) with a bigger chance (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with Regex :

This will do :

```
var a= '3(10)'.match(/\((.*?)\)/)
alert(a[1]) ;//10
```

The captured group will appear in the second index of the array (1)

Regarding your other comment/question :

> I have a[0] = '3(10,5) 7(9,4)'; 10 and 9 are chances the task is to
>   get the number (3 or 7) with a bigger chance (10)

```
var finalNumber=-1;
var finalChance=-1;


var a = '3(10,5) 7(9,4)';
var m=a.match(/(\d+?)\((\d+?)\,/g);

for (var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
  {
     var number=m[i].match(/(\d+)\(/)[1]
     var chance=m[i].match(/\((\d+)\,/)[1]

     if (+chance>+finalChance) 
     { 
        finalChance=chance;
        finalNumber=number;
     }
  }
console.log(finalNumber)
```

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wagumu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, but I meant abit other: I need to get a number with a bigger chance by random. It means as bigger chance-number as more chance to get the item.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` function to split your string with brackets two times :

```
 var first_split = n[0].split(')')[0];  //first_split will return "3(10"
 var result = first_split.split('(')[1]; //second split will return "10";

 //To reduce the code you can do it in 1 line like this
 var result = n[0].split(')')[0].split('(')[1];  // result = "10"
```

Comment: one more question: I have 

    a[0] = '3(10,5) 7(9,4)';
10 and 9 are chances
the task is to get the number (3  or 7) with a bigger chance (10)